# Java: Sudoku puzzle generation not working properly

Tags: android, while-loop, sudoku

I am trying to make a sudoku app, and in it I am generating each puzzle. My generation, I thought, should work flawlessly, yet my app continues to crash. I think it is coming from here and on:

```
If(_band == 2) {
    while((band2.contains(placeholder)) || (band2.get((int)(_stack - 1)).doubleValue() == band1.get((int)(_stack - 1)).doubleValue())) {
        placeholder = SketchwareUtil.getRandom((int)(1),(int)(9)); 
    }
    band2.add(Double.valueOf(placeholder));
}
```

This goes from band2 to band9, checking each band before it for a duplicate number in the same position and checking its band for a duplicate number.

If it helps, band3 generation looks like this:

```
If(_band == 3) {
    while((band3.contains(placeholder)) || (band3.get((int)(_stack - 1)).doubleValue() == band1.get((int)(_stack - 1)).doubleValue()) || (band3.get((int)(_stack - 1)).doubleValue() == band2.get((int)(_stack - 1)).doubleValue())) {
        placeholder = SketchwareUtil.getRandom((int)(1)), ((int)(9));
    } 
    band3.add(Double.valueOf(placeholder));
}
```

The error code is always:
Invalid List Operation
: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: All code should be indented by at least 4 spaces, that's why.

Comment: It is described in the [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help),  And there are even little short-cut widgets in the editor window to do it!

Comment: It would help if you could post your stack trace as well. what errors do you get?